# PHP GD Don't decompress JPGs?

Tags: php, gd

I have a script which re-sizes images, my issue is the laptop which is running this script has 4GB of memory, but it struggles to display - lets say 5 - the images at a decent speed.

Manipulating the images takes time due to their size also, I was wondering if there is a way to manipulate them without decompressing them (someone suggested somewhere that by loading a 3MB JPG it may decompress into 14MB) or even compressing the images further?

My client does not want to lower the resolution of the images for easier handling. If it isn't possible to speed up the processing of the images then the client is going have to put up with slow processing of the large images.

Comment: I'm not sure what is being asked here. At all.

Comment: Alas, it seems that http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php converts the image from JPEG into GD's internal format; therefore, it is not possible to re-size the images using GD without decoding them from JPEG. (Is it necessary to _display_ the images while resizing them? Most of the resizing I've used in PHP ran headless, and 4 GB is not a small amount of RAM)